# Cannot play audio on audio player made by audioplayers packag and recorded from audio recorder created from flutter_sound package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, flutter-packages

I have used [flutter_sound](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sound) package to record audio and the audio is getting recorded also but I am not able to play the audio from the audio player I created using the [audioplayers](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers).

**Below is the Code**

```
 class _ReviewBox extends State<ReviewBox> {
 final recorder = FlutterSoundRecorder();
 final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
 bool isPlaying = false;
 Duration duration = Duration.zero;
 Duration position = Duration.zero;
 bool isRecorderReady = false;
 @override
 void initState() {
 super.initState();

 initRecorder();
 setAudio();
  audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
  setState(() {
    isPlaying = state == PlayerState.playing;
  });
});
// Listen to audio duration
audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((newDuration) {
  setState(() {
    duration = newDuration;
  });
});
// Listen to audio position
audioPlayer.onPositionChanged.listen((newPosition) {
  setState(() {
    position = newPosition;
  });
});
 }

   Future setAudio() async {
   // audioPlayer.setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.stop);
   final audioFile = await stop();
   print(' audio file in setAudio :$audioFile');
   if (audioFile != null) {
   audioPlayer.setSource(
    audioFile,
      );
    }
   }

   @override
   void dispose() {
   recorder.closeRecorder();
   super.dispose();
   }

   Future initRecorder() async {
   final status = await Permission.microphone.request();
   if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
   throw 'Microphone permission not granted';
   }
   await recorder.openRecorder();
   isRecorderReady = true;
   }

   Future record() async {
   if (!isRecorderReady) return;
   await recorder.startRecorder(toFile: 'audio');
   }

   

   Future stop() async {
   if (!isRecorderReady) return;
   final path = await recorder.stopRecorder();
   final audioFile = File(path!);
   print('Recorded audio :$audioFile');
   }
```

> Future stop() method stops the audio recorder and saves it in a File type.
> Then I have called the "audiofile" variable to setAudio() method which is a function from another package named audioplayers which sets audio file into the audio player to play the audiofile.

I have tried to print also in setAudio method but it won't print only even when I have called it in initState().

[This is my DebugConsole Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIWBA.jpg)
You can see the file type path in my console and when I play and resume the recorder nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you got this code from this tutorial? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bxn8k9F5JiM&t=13s&ab_channel=HeyFlutter%E2%80%A4com

I ran into the same problem. When you save your recording, make sure you include the extension or else audioplayers won't play the file.

```
await recorder.startRecorder(toFile: 'audio.aac');
```